# Thread-safe std::map accessor

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, synchronization, stl

After learning that `std::map` containers are not inherently atomic and therefore not thread-safe (check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9147258/object-of-shared-pointer-being-deleted-while-instances-of-shared-ptr-are-still-i) related Stack Overflow question and usage example), I decided to create code that would allow concurrent access to the container.

```
#ifndef MAP_GUARD_H_
#define MAP_GUARD_H_

/*
This class was designed to make the standard map synchronized for the basic functions.
The intent was for it to be filled with shared_ptr as the value in the pair.
A Grand Central Dispatch serial queue is used for syncronising access to the map rather than raw mutexes.
*/

// A macro to disallow the copy constructor and operator= functions
// This should be used in the private: declarations for a class
#define DISALLOW_COPY_AND_ASSIGN(TypeName) \
  TypeName(const TypeName&);               \
  void operator=(const TypeName&)

#include <map>
#ifdef WIN32
#include <xdispatch\dispatch.h>
#else
#include <xdispatch/dispatch.h>
#endif

template <class K, class V>
class map_guard
{
public:
    map_guard();
    ~map_guard();
    void clear();
    void erase(const K& key);
    void insert(const K& key, const V& value);
    /* Take a snopshot of map_ and fill target with it (usefull if you want to use iterators) */
    void fill_map(std::map<K, V>& target) const;
    V find(const K& key) const;
    size_t size() const;
    bool empty() const;
    void swap(std::map<K, V>& map);
private:
    void make_swap(std::map<K, V>* map);
    void get(std::map<K, V>* target) const;
    void get(const K& key, V* target) const;
    void get_empty(bool* empty) const;
    void get_size(size_t* size) const;
    std::map<K, V> map_;
    xdispatch::queue* dispatch_queue_;
    DISALLOW_COPY_AND_ASSIGN(map_guard);
};

template <class K, class V>
map_guard<K, V>::map_guard() : dispatch_queue_(0)
{
    dispatch_queue_ = new xdispatch::queue("test");
}

template <class K, class V>
map_guard<K, V>::~map_guard()
{
    if(dispatch_queue_)
    {
        delete dispatch_queue_;
        dispatch_queue_ = 0;
    }
}

template <class K, class V>
void map_guard<K, V>::clear()
{
    dispatch_queue_->sync(${
        map_.clear();
    });
}

template <class K, class V>
void map_guard<K, V>::erase(const K& key)
{
    dispatch_queue_->sync(${
        map_.erase(key);
    });
}

template <class K, class V>
void map_guard<K, V>::insert(const K& key, const V& value)
{
    dispatch_queue_->sync(${
        map_[key] = value;
    });
}

template <class K, class V>
void map_guard<K, V>::get(std::map<K, V>* target) const
{
    dispatch_queue_->sync(${
        target->insert(map_.begin(), map_.end());
    });
}

template <class K, class V>
void map_guard<K, V>::get(const K& key, V* target) const
{
    dispatch_queue_->sync(${
        std::map<K, V>::const_iterator it = map_.find(key);
        if(it != map_.end())
        {
            *target = it->second;
        }
    });
}

template <class K, class V>
void map_guard<K, V>::fill_map(std::map<K, V>& target) const
{
    get(&target);
}

template <class K, class V>
V map_guard<K, V>::find(const K& key) const
{
    V temp;
    get(key, &temp);
    return temp;
}

template <class K, class V>
void map_guard<K, V>::get_size(size_t* size) const
{
    dispatch_queue_->sync(${
        *size = map_.size();
    });
}

template <class K, class V>
size_t map_guard<K, V>::size() const
{
    size_t size;
    get_size(&size);
    return size;
}

template <class K, class V>
void map_guard<K, V>::get_empty(bool* empty) const
{
    dispatch_queue_->sync(${
        *empty = map_.empty();
    });
}

template <class K, class V>
bool map_guard<K, V>::empty() const
{
    bool empty;
    get_empty(&empty);
    return empty;
}

template <class K, class V>
void map_guard<K, V>::swap(std::map<K, V>& map)
{
    make_swap(&map);
}

template <class K, class V>
void map_guard<K, V>::make_swap(std::map<K, V>* map)
{
    dispatch_queue_->sync(${
        map_.swap(*map);
    });
}

#endif
```

Is this a valid method for solving the problem? Are there other ways that may be more efficient?

Comment: Back or forward slashes will work on Windows; don't need that #ifdef WIN32 block

Answer (score 3):

If you would like to try out c++0x, you have `std::mutex` and `std::lock_guard`. An example forwarding some of methods in `std::map` is shown as following:

```
//hello.cc

#include <map>
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>

template <class K, class V, class Compare = std::less<K>, class Allocator = std::allocator<std::pair<const K, V> > >
class guarded_map {
    private:
        std::map<K, V, Compare, Allocator> _map;
        std::mutex _m;

    public:
        void set(K key, V value) {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(this->_m);
            this->_map[key] = value;
        }

        V & get(K key) {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(this->_m);
            return this->_map[key];
        }

        bool empty() {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(this->_m);
            return this->_map.empty();
        }

        // other public methods you need to implement
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    guarded_map<int, int> m;
    m.set(1, 10);
    m.set(2, 20);
    m.set(4, 30);
    std::cout<<"m[2]="<<m.get(2)<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

To compile, you will probably need to add some special flag to your compiler. For example, g++ would be:

```
g++ -std=c++0x -o hello hello.cc
```

The `std::lock_guard` here makes things much easier. It locks the mutex in its constructor, and automatically unlock the mutex in its destructor, which means you can initialize a `std::lock_guard` at the beginning of a block you need to synchronize concurrency, and leave it there, as the lock will be released when this block exit.

Answer (score 1):

Use boost::noncopyable instead of DISALLOW_COPY_AND_ASSIGN:

```
   template <class K, class V>
   class map_guard: boost::noncopyable
   {
```

1. boost::noncopyable resides in the first line instead of deep internals
2. DRY -- you do not need to type `map_guard` again
3. noncopyable.hpp is a small header-only library

---

Probably, you do not need special case `#include <xdispatch\dispatch.h>` because compiler will translate `#include <xdispatch/dispatch.h>` for you.

---

Next, I have a vague idea "what an xdispatch is", but it seems to me that placing block in a queue is a costly operation, so locking have to be used. Also, may be lockless algorith will be appropriate, say, based on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap

Comment: Wouldn't `#include <xdispatch/dispatch.h>` work in Windows anyway? Windows supports both characters as path separators.

Comment: @seand My last compiler run under Windows was around 10 years ago.